# Embed Power BI dashboard issue

Tags: asp.net, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I need to embed  Power BI dashboards (on permise) into an asp.net application, so I have created following HTML file:

```
<html>
 <iframe width="900" height="900" src="http://MyReportServer/reports/powerbi/accounts&rs:embed=true" 
   frameborder="1" allowFullScreen="true">
 </iframe>
</html>
```

And I got following error when open the HTML file:

> Server Error in '/' Application. Runtime Error Description: An
>   application error occurred on the server. The current custom error
>   settings for this application prevent the details of the application
>   error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could,
>   however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

I also set customErrors off in web.conf of Power Bi report server as follow:

```
<customErrors mode="on" />
</system.web>
```

But still get the same error even on the local machine and can't see the details of the application error.

Comment: I assume that when you go directly to the PowerBI report it works?

Comment: Yes, it works directly.

Comment: So if you put hte URL `http://MyReportServer/reports/powerbi/accounts&rs:embed=true` in your browser it's fine? That's weird because your web page is static.

Comment: When I use "http://MyReportServer/reports/powerbi/accounts" it works, but when I embed in an iframe I get an error.

Answer (score 0):

After attempting to embed the dashboard using an iframe, we encountered security or access issues. However, accessing the dashboard URL directly in a browser works without any problem. For more effective embedding of dashboards, its recommend utilizing the Embed URL and Access Token method.

Here are some references for clarification - [Solved: Embed Power BI dashboard in ASP.Net core - Microsoft Fabric Community](https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Developer/Embed-Power-BI-dashboard-in-ASP-Net-core/m-p/273279)

Links for generating Embed URL and Access:

- [Token for the dashboard- Embed Token - Dashboards GenerateTokenInGroup - REST API (Power BI Power BI REST APIs) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/embed-token/dashboards-generate-token-in-group#code-try-0)
- [Dashboards - Get Dashboard In Group - REST API (Power BI Power BI REST APIs) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/dashboards/get-dashboard-in-group)

Please let me know if you still face the issue.